# Retrieving a resultset through an oracle procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have very limited skill on pl-sql and I have a very complicated situation.

In mssql i have a procedure that returns a result set with varying number of columns from varying source tables depending on parameters provided.

In oracle i am having difficulty to create a proc which does the same.

I need to generate query inside, execute it and return the result.

I searched a lot and tried a lot of things. Now i now that the best way to do this is execute query into a cursor which i can not manage to do. Now all i can do is generate query and execute it - and have no visible result.

Any help ?

Thanks

Edit: Being more specific: how can i execute my dynamically generated query into a cursor or reutn with a local temporary table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
create or replace procedure dynamic_cursor_demo
    ( p_some_expression in varchar2
    , p_results out sys_refcursor )
as
begin
    open p_results for
        'select ' || p_some_expression || ' as demo from dual';
end dynamic_cursor_demo;
```

(If you have Oracle 12c you can also use [implicit statement results](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DRDAA/migr_tools_feat.htm#DRDAA230). Examples in the docs.)

Comment: that looks good but after desperate hours i decided to move the business logic into application rather than oracle. if need be i'll come back and try this. many thanks.